# How to secure a URL service?

Tags: php, html, security

I use on my server a Text-to-Speech Synthesis platform (probably written in Java).

While the above application is running on my server, users can get audio as a URL to a wav file using the embedded HTML `<audio>` tag, as follows:

`<audio controls>
   <source src=”http://myserver.com:59125/process?INPUT_TEXT=Hello%20world” type=”audio/wav”>
</audio>`

In the above ‘*src*’ attribute, ‘*process*’ requests the synthesis of some text using local port 59125.

My concern is that I might start seeing performance issues and out of memory errors, which would cause the TTS Synthesis platform server (but not the website) to crash every few days, apparently triggered by one or more entities abusing it as some sort of webservice for their own applications.

I wish to secure the URL requests so that a third party couldn't use my text-to-speech server for audio clips not related to my website.

How to secure the URL service?

Comment: What kind of server is it? Apache? nginx? IIS?

Comment: Secure it from what, exactly?

Comment: From not using this URL on my server to generate for anybody audio clips.

Comment: Use HTTP authentication and HTTPS. There you go.

Comment: I don't want to to provide a user name and password when making a request (please see my comment below to 'Scott Arciszewski').

Comment: So you have a *public* website in which you embed said `<audio>` element, so any random *public* visitor needs to be able to access this TTS URL?

Comment: Yes, as long as the user came from my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it this URL is embedded in a *public* website, so any random *public* user needs to be able to access this URL to download the file. This makes it virtually impossible to secure *as is*.

The biggest problem is that you're publicly exposing a useful service which is usable for anyone to do something useful. I.e., just by requesting a URL which I construct, I can get your server to do useful work for me (turn *my* text into speech). The core problem here is that the input text is fully configurable by the end user.

To take away any incentive for any random person to use your server, you need to take away the ability for anyone to convert any random text. If you are the only one who wants to be in charge of what input texts are allowed, you'll have to either whitelist and validate the input, or identify it using ids. E.g., instead of

```
http://myserver.com:59125/process?INPUT_TEXT=Hello%20world
```

your URLs look more like:

```
http://myserver.com:59125/process?input_id=42
```

`42` is substituted to `Hello world` on the server. Unknown ids won't be served.

Alternatively, again, validate and whitelist:

```
GET http://myserver.com:59125/process?INPUT_TEXT=Foo%20bar

404 Not Found
Speech for "Foo bar" does not exist.
```

For either approach, you'll need some sort of proxy in-between instead of directly exposing your TTS engine to the world. This proxy can also cache the resulting file to avoid repeatedly converting the same input again and again.

The end result would work like this:

1. `GET http://myserver.com/tts?input=Hello%20world`
2. `myserver.com` validates input, returns 403 or 404 for invalid input
3. `myserver.com` proxies a request to `localhost:59125?INPUT_TEXT=Hello%20World` if not already cached
4. `myserver.com` caches the result
5. `myserver.com` serves the result

This can be accomplished in any number of ways using any number of different web servers and/or CGI programs which do the necessary steps 2 and possibly 3.

Comment: The TTS Synthesizer accept only the specific syntax in the URL to process speech requests, so I cannot change the URL request (“input_id=42”), but I want to check your advice for a proxy in-between instead of directly exposing the TTS engine to the world. For that I need to understand how the server knows when the audio tag gets called?

Comment: The audio tag doesn't "get called"; at some point the browser will **request the URL** from your server. Your proxy needs to handle this **URL request** correctly. That's the standard operation of any HTTP server, you just need to customize your URL handling.

Comment: Okay, let me ask it different.. how the server can identify a URL request from that specific port (59125)?

Comment: You've got it backwards. You do not request to that port directly. You change the URL that gets requested. The new URL is a proxy address, which conditionally forwards the request to the TTS engine.

Comment: I will accept the answer, hopefully I can implement it. Thx.

Comment: [SOLVED]: “Don’t deploy your application in Jetty, deploy Jetty in your application”. This is what I did to solve it (Jetty is a Java HTTP Web server).

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what server you are using. Possible methods are:

- Authentication: Use a username and password combination or ask for a SSH certificate; this could be provided via cURL when one webservice requests another one
- IP whitelist: allow only specific IP's to access this server

IP whitelist example in Apache:

```
Deny from all
# server himself
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168.1.14   # maybe some additional internal network IP
Allow from 192.168.1.36   # or another machine in the local network
Allow from 93.184.216.34  # or some machine somewhere else on the web
```

Comment: I can’t use IP whitelist or username/password, since I want that anybody that browsing my website to be able to use the embedded sound content in documents (play the sound). All I need is to prevent using this URL of my server to generate for anybody audio clips.

Comment: So you want anyone to be able to access the device, but you don't want anyone to be able to use it? Whitelist the valid inputs.

Comment: I want anybody to use the audio tag on my website (regular web document), but I don’t want somebody to copy this URL (using the console log) and past it to his browser.. and now you’re using my server without permission (and get audio clips processed on my server).

Answer (score 1):

your best bet is using the answer above from feeela to limit the usage of the TTS platform to a said webserver (this will be where the users request the audio from and where your security logic should be implemented)

after that you need to write a "proxy" script that gets a token generated on-the-fly from the page that hosts the audio tag with a logic/method of your choice and check its validity (you can use the session/other user data and a salt), if valid it should call the TTS engine and return the audio, otherwise generate an error/a redirect/whatever you want

Comment: Could you explain shortly how to write the "proxy" script that gets the generated token? Do you mean that if the TTS Synthesis platform is in Java, do I need to wrap it as a Java servlet and check validity on the server? I’m not sure how to implement the script that you mentioned..

Comment: i would generate a token on the fly on the page that is going to call the <audio> tag based on some data (ip address plus UTS plus a secret salt, mix and match however you want, it just needs to be unique) then store it on the server as key->value with the text you want to translate, when the audio tag gets called you will need to pass that token to your proxy script which will read it and check it against your stored data, you can use the token itself as a key to retrieve the text you want to translate and if you find it you just call your TTS otherwise return an error; hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the solution that you offered, probably I can implement a hashing algorithm on the client side, but how would the server know “when the audio tag gets called”?

Comment: you can render the audio tag after the calling page has already calculated the hash and after you determined the text to be translated (that depends on how your page works), the audio tag should be rendered with an src like "yourproxyscript.php?token=generated_token" and the proxy script should contact the tts server and in case the token is valid retrieve the raw data and echo it with mimetype audio/wav or accordingly to the kind of data it generates

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "securing it".

- Maybe you want it to only be accessible to certain users? In that case, you have an easy answer: issue each user with login credentials that they need to enter when they visit the site, and pass those credentials through to the API. Anyone without valid credentials will be unable to use the API. Job done.
- Or maybe you want it to work for anyone, but only to be used from specific sites? This is more difficult, because any kind of authentication key you have would need to be within the site's Javascript code, and thus visible to someone wanting to copy it. There isn't a foolproof solution, but the best solution I can suggest is to link each API key to the URL of the site that owns it. Then use the HTTP referrer header to check that calls made using a given API key are being called from the correct site. HTTP requests can be spoofed, including the referrer header, so this isn't foolproof, but will prevent most unauthorised use -- someone would have to go a fair distance out of their way to get around it (they'd probably have to set up a proxy server that forwarded your API requests and spoofed the headers). This is unlikely to happen unless your API is an incredibly valuable asset, but if you are worried about that, then you could make it harder for them by having the API keys change frequently and randomly.

But whatever else you do, the very first thing you need to do to secure it is to switch to HTTPS rather than HTTP.